# How to check object level permission efficiently in DRF?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

**Scenario:** In **DRF** I had to write following lines of code **to check permission** for the user

```
class RetrieveCampaignListView(APIView) :

authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]


def get(self, request , *args, **kwargs):

    if request.user.has_perm('campaign.view_campaign'):

        try:
            #some view code
        
        except:

            return Response({"status":False}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    else:
        return Response({"status":"Sorry User is not permitted"})
```

But I want to shorten the

```
request.user.has_perm('campaign.view_camapign') and it's else condition
```

into something like this.

```
@check_permission('campaign.view_campaign')
```

Any Help Would be highly appericiated.

Comment: Have a look at: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DRF custom permissions:

```
from rest_framework import permissions


class ViewCampaignPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    message = 'Sorry User is not permitted'

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user.has_perm('campaign.view_campaign'):

class RetrieveCampaignListView(APIView) :
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ViewCampaignPermission]
    ...
```

See: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions

or if you really want a decorator, you can use something like:

```
from functools import wraps
from rest_framework.views import APIView

def has_permission(permission):
    def has_permission_decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def has_permission_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            request = args[0].request
            if not request.user.has_perm(permission):
                return Response(status='Sorry User is not permitted'})
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return has_permission_wrapper
    return has_permission_decorator


class RetrieveCampaignListView(APIView):
    @has_permission('campaign.view_campaign')
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

But this will only work for one permission string.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , but what if I want to implement another permission say campaign.add_campaign  ? I should create another custom permission  may be AddCampaignPermission which I am trying to avoid. I want to make a common decorator or function or class whose input parameter is permission code_name .

Comment: I want to impement something like @check_permission("permission_codename") instead of creating whole custom permission for each code_name. Would love to hear feedback on this @bdbd

Comment: Edited. See if the decorator makes sense. But I would advise going against the decorator approach, as this will only work for one permission.

Comment: decorator approach helps work for multiple permission implementation since code_name would be the parameter passing to it.

Comment: @bdbd why not maintain a list of the permissions you want to check and you can iteratively check which permissions are satisfied.

Comment: @bdbd  Everything works fine but I am unclear about the concept of args[0].request can you explain on it please.